# Bugged Game Center Matchmaker appearance

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I am developing multiplayer for my game and I have encountered following issue
I am using Cocos 2d 2.1 , iOS 6 and following code to show matchmaker (Landscape orientation)

```
 AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:4 viewController:[app navController] delegate:self];
```

And thats how it appears[image]

Following code is used for that function

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
             viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                   delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

matchStarted = NO;
self.match = nil;
self.presentingViewController = viewController;
delegate = theDelegate;
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc =
[[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

is this code in HelloWorldLayer? if so is that the first layer that the director calls? I have the same problem but it's fixes if I follow strictly the cocos2d template that was created for me. Meaning that I use the IntroLayer as the initial layer and from there it transitions into the HelloWorldLayer where I have the game center code. I think it has something to do with the director being loaded too late but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to push on a `UIViewController`, but **you only have a UIView in your app, and no UIViewController**.  Let me guess, you do not have a `rootViewController`.

If you are working from the `EAGLView` template, **you must declare a UIViewController for the UIView**.  This can be as simple as,

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
  window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
  window.rootViewController.view = glView; // MUST SET THIS UP,
  // NOW THE EAGLView HAS A UIViewController.

  [glView startAnimation];
}
```

Then, anytime you want to push on one of those GameKit `UIViewControllers`, use the `presentViewController` method of your Window object's `rootViewController`

For example:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:TRUE completion:^(void){puts("DONE");} ] ;
```

The bugginess will go away and the window will be correctly formed.